# Почему wordpress не сохраняет опции плагина?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Пишу небольшой плагин и столкнулся с тем, что WP не сохраняет опции.
Где ошибка?

```
<?php
  function build_calc_admin_page() {
  global $pagenow;
    if ( $pagenow == 'options-general.php' && $_GET['page'] == 'build-calc' ) {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
      <h1><?php echo get_admin_page_title() ?></h1>
      <table class="form-table">
        <tbody>
          <form action="<?php admin_url( 'options.php' ); ?>" method="POST">
            <?php
              settings_fields( 'one_floor_group' );     
              do_settings_sections( 'one_floor_page' ); 
              submit_button();
            ?>
          </form>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <?php 
    }
  }

  add_action( 'admin_init', 'plugin_settings' );
  function plugin_settings() {

    register_setting( 'one_floor_group', 'one_floor_group', 'sanitize_callback' );

    add_settings_section( 'section_one_floor', 'Одноэтажный дом', '', 'one_floor_page' );

    $fields = array(
      'svai' => 'Фундамент на сваях:',
      'rostverk' => 'Ростверк на столбах:',
      'lenta' => 'Фундамент ленточный утепленный:',
      'plita' => 'Фундамент монолитная плита:',
      'karkas' => 'Каркас:',
      'gazobeton' => 'Газобетон:',
      'kirpich' => 'Кирпич:',
      'zhb_perekrytie' => 'Железобетонное перекрытие:',
      'der_perekrytie' => 'Деревянное для каркасного дома:',
      'derGB_perekrytie' => 'Деревянное для газобетона:',
      'metallocherepitsa' => 'Металлочерепица:',
      'myagkaya_cherepitsa' => 'Мягкая черепица:',
      'cementno_peschanaya_cherepitsa' => 'Цементно-песчаная черепица BRAAS:',
      'poly_1_etazh' => 'Полы первого этажа (стяжка):',
      'okna' => 'Окна:',
      'fasad_svesy' => 'Фасад и свесы:',
      'transport' => 'Транспорт:',
      'dostavka' => 'Доставка газобетона (кирпича):'
    );

    foreach ($fields as $field => $name){
      add_settings_field( $field, $name, 'fill_field_one_floor', 'one_floor_page', 'section_one_floor', $args = array('field' => $field) );
    }
  }

  function fill_field_one_floor($args) {
    $field_name = $args['field'];
    $val = get_option('one_floor_group');
    $val = $val[$field_name];
  ?>
    <input type="number" step="any" name="build_calc_one_floor[<?php echo $field_name; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $val ) ?>" />

    <?php
  }

  function activate_build_calc() {
    add_options_page( 'Строительный калькулятор', 'Строительный калькулятор', 'manage_options', 'build-calc', 'build_calc_admin_page' );
  }

  add_action( 'admin_menu', 'activate_build_calc' );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Уберите `sanitize_callback` из `register_setting`. Третий параметр должен быть массивом аргументов или быть указателем на существующую функцию очистки.